# Direct Products

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $A, B, C, D$ are groups and $B\cong C \times D$. Show: $A \times B\cong A \times C \times D$

What map should I use which will help me use the given isomorphism? Do I have to define two maps?

Thank you!!

Comment: Let $\varphi:B\to C\times D$ be an isomorphism. How can we lift this to an isomorphism $\tilde\varphi:A\times B\to A\times C\times D$? I should say: you know where you want elements of $B$ to go. Where should elements of $A$ go?

Comment: @ Frank McGovern: Thanks for the hint! So, I would use
φ~:A×B→A×C×D such that φ~(a,b)=(a,b,c,d)?

Answer (score 1):

One way to prove an isomorphism is to construct homomorphisms in both directions and show they're mutual inverses. If $f$ is an isomorphisms from $B$ to $C\times D,$
can you do this with the maps $g:A\times B\to A\times C\times D, g(a,b)=(a,f(b))$
and $h:A\times C\times D\to A\times B, h(a,c,d)=(a,f^{-1}(c,d))$?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Combine two isomorphisms component-wise: if $h:B\to C\times D$ is an isomorphism, consider

$$\begin{array}{rc}
A&\times&B\\
\text{id}_A\downarrow&&\;\;\downarrow h\\
A&\times&(C\times D)
\end{array}$$

Comment: I am using the map: φ~:A×B→A×C×D such that φ~(a,b)=(a,b,c,d)? Am I on the right track?

Comment: @James: Clearly not, since your output is in $A\times B\times C\times D$, not in $A\times C\times D$. Your map from $A\times B$ to $A\times C\times D$ is going to have to make use of some isomorphism $h:B\to C\times D$, and it will produce ordered **triples** whose entries are all built somehow from the $a$ and $b$ of the input $\langle a,b\rangle$.